# Replace file with specific name java

Tags: java

I make a java code that copy paste a file from a source to a destination.
My problem now that in every run a new file is pasted in the destination with numerical name. What I want is, to paste that file in the destination with specific name. And on running one more time a new file is created and replaced by the older. In order to get only one file.
I have used the following code:

```
String b = System.getProperty("user.home");
String src = b + "\\Desktop\\Nouveau dossier\\History";
String des = b + "\\Desktop\\Nouveau dossier2";

File from = new File(src);
File to = new File(des);

System.out.println("tt");

try {
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, to);
        long size = from.length();

        System.out.println("rr" + size);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first the `file` variable is not defined anywhere so you are calling function `exists()` on a `null` object.

Here's the code that might work for you (I replaced references to `file` variable with `from` which appears to be your intent):

```
try {
    if (from.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(from, to);
        long size = from.length();

        System.out.println("rr" + size);
    } else { 
        System.out.println("No file");

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a real answer to the question. Pls write a comment next time.